# Podofo PDF table and AutoPageBreak

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

Can somebody help me to get working the AutoPageBreak function of Podofo::PdfTable class?

I write so

```
table1.SetAutoPageBreak(true,
            [](PoDoFo::PdfRect &rect, void* pCustom)->PoDoFo::PdfPage*{
                PoDoFo::PdfPage *pPage = new PoDoFo::PdfPage(rect,(PoDoFo::PdfStreamedDocument*)pCustom);
                rect = PoDoFo::PdfRect(0,0,pPage->GetPageSize().GetWidth(), pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight());
                cout << "qui" << endl;
                return pPage;
            }, (void*) document);
```

the function is called correctly but does nothing, the first page is correctly created but the new page is not created.

http://podofo.sourceforge.net/doc/html/classPoDoFo_1_1PdfTable.html#ac33e4bf489d3b7232deae271b8dc552a

the rest of source code is here

```
document = new PoDoFo::PdfStreamedDocument("doc.pdf");
PoDoFo::PdfPainter painter;
PoDoFo::PdfTable table1 = PoDoFo::PdfTable(2, length);
    
table1.SetAutoPageBreak(true,
            [](PoDoFo::PdfRect &rect, void* pCustom)->PoDoFo::PdfPage*{
                PoDoFo::PdfPage *pPage = new PoDoFo::PdfPage(rect,(PoDoFo::PdfStreamedDocument*)pCustom);
                rect = PoDoFo::PdfRect(0,0,pPage->GetPageSize().GetWidth(), pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight());
                cout << "qui" << endl;
                return pPage;
            }, (void*) document);
PoDoFo::PdfSimpleTableModel* tablemodel1 = new PoDoFo::PdfSimpleTableModel(2, length);
    
PoDoFo::PdfPage* pPage = document->CreatePage(PoDoFo::PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PoDoFo::ePdfPageSize_A4, true));
    painter.SetPage(pPage);
    PoDoFo::PdfFont* pFont = document->CreateFontSubset("NotoSansMono", false, false, false, PoDoFo::PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalStandardEncodingInstance(), "NotoSansMono-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf");
    //PoDoFo::PdfFont* pFont = document.CreateFont("Courier");
pFont->SetFontSize(8);
painter.SetFont(pFont);
tablemodel1->SetFont(pFont);
tablemodel1->SetForegroundColor(PoDoFo::PdfColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
tablemodel1->SetBorderEnabled(true);
tablemodel1->SetBorderWidth(0.5);
tablemodel1->SetAlignment(PoDoFo::EPdfVerticalAlignment::ePdfVerticalAlignment_Top);
tablemodel1->SetWordWrapEnabled(true);
painter.DrawTextAligned(20, pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight()-20, pPage->GetPageSize().GetWidth(), "Riassunto giornaliero risorse", PoDoFo::EPdfAlignment::ePdfAlignment_Center);
string text = "";       
vector<OggettoEventoItem*>* listaOggettiEventi;
vector<EventoItem*>* eventoItem;
double rowheight[(int)oggettiSel->size()];
double totrowheight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (int)oggettiSel->size(); i++)
{
    tablemodel1->SetText(0, i, oggettiSel->at(i)->GetLabel().ToStdString());
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)listaOggettiEventi->size(); j++)
    {
        text += "...";  
    }
    tablemodel1->SetText(1, i, text);
    char newline = '\n';
 
    int count = std::count(text.begin(), text.end(), newline);
    if(count > 0)
        rowheight[i] = count * 20;
    else
        rowheight[i] = 20;
        
    totrowheight += rowheight[i];
        
    text = "";
}
table1.SetModel(tablemodel1);
double colwidth[2] = { 150, pPage->GetPageSize().GetWidth() - 150 - 40};
table1.SetColumnWidths(colwidth);
table1.SetRowHeights(rowheight);
table1.SetTableWidth(pPage->GetPageSize().GetWidth()-40);
table1.SetTableHeight(pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight()-60);
table1.Draw(20, pPage->GetPageSize().GetHeight()- 40, &painter);
painter.FinishPage();
document->Close();
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
table1.SetAutoPageBreak(true,
            [](PoDoFo::PdfRect &rect, void* pCustom)->PoDoFo::PdfPage*{
                PoDoFo::PdfPage *pPage = ((PoDoFo::PdfStreamedDocument*)pCustom)->CreatePage(PoDoFo::PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PoDoFo::ePdfPageSize_A4, true));

                return pPage;
            }, (void*) document);
```

I solved, was more easy than expected.